# How to achieve a shopping cart functionality in a stateless REST implementation?

Tags: rest

That would mean client always has the complete representation of the cart and server does not maintain the cart in the session.

It will be easier to implement in a single page app or a native mobile app where you do not have page transitions and cart data is available as a JSON object locally.

What about a traditional web app that involves page transitions? What could be some of the options available? Store the content in hidden fields or even in a JSON object when the page is rendered by the server. What do you recommend?